# Closure of Sets

Tags: real-analysis

> Given $$S=\bigl\{\tfrac{1}{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\bigr\}$$ and $$T=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigl(0,\tfrac{1}{n}\bigr),$$ what is $\operatorname{cl}S \space \text{and} \operatorname{cl}T?$

*Note that "$\operatorname{cl}$" stands for closure.

I know that the closure of a set S is $S \cup S'$, where $S'$ is the set of all accumulation points of $S$. I know that a point $x\in\mathbb{R}$ is an accumulation point of $S$ if every deleted neighbourhood of $x$ contains a point of $S$. I know that a deleted neighbourhood of $x$ is the set $\{y\in\mathbb{R}:0<|x-y|<\epsilon\}$.

I (think) I understand the definitions above, but I'm not sure how to tackle this. I think my problem is that I don't understand how to get $S'$. Any suggestions?

Comment: Before doing anything else, you should determine what $T$ is: you can't find its closure until you know what it is.

Comment: In a metric space (such as the real line), the characterization of accumulation points (AKA limit points) as limits of sequences should help with your intuition. Figuring out what the accumulation points *should* be is the first step; proving it is, in this case, fairly simple.

Comment: $T=(0,1)\cap (0,\frac{1}{2})\cap (0,\frac{1}{3})\cap ... \cap(0,\frac{1}{n})$ is going to be the empty set. ( I think)

Comment: @SujaanKunalan, can you prove it? I recommend a proof by contradiction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part has been answered before in other questions:
[determine the closures of the set k={1/n| n is a positive integer}](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44913/determine-the-closures-of-the-set-k-1-n-n-is-a-positive-integer)
[Determine the closure of the set $K=\{\frac{1}{n}\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$ under each of topologies](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75162/determine-the-closure-of-the-set-k-frac1n-mid-n-in-mathbb-n-under-eac)

For the second part, you should show that $T=\emptyset$.

Notice that $x\in T$ if and only if $x>0$ and $x<1/n$ for each $n$. If the inequality $x<1/n$ holds for every $n$, then
$$x \le \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac1n=0.$$
So you have that $x$ fulfills simultaneously the inequalities $x>0$ and $x\le0$. This means that no such $x$ exists.

Comment: Or you could use the Archimedean property directly.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $0$ is only limit point of $S$ and your $T=\emptyset$

Comment: How did you come to this conclusion?

Comment: take any $\epsilon>0$ neighborhood of $0$, you will get a point from $S$, infact the sequence $1\over n$ converges to $0$ as $n\to \infty$, use Archimedian property to conclude these.